# Percorrer um arquivo.txt e extrair uma "PK" do arquivo

Tags: php, file-put-contents

Comecei a pouco tempo com a programação em **PHP** e estou com algumas dificuldade em entender algumas funções enfim, estou participando de um projeto, e como parte do projeto preciso armazenar um `array` em um `arquivo.txt` que eu pessoa ler depois(*até aqui blz, salvei o arquivo com file_input_contents, e usei a função serialize para que seja possível gravar o array dentro de um arquivo*).

*A minha dificuldade está é:*

***1)*** Como eu faço para ler o arquivo?
R: funções `fopen()`? Blz, como eu percorro esse arquivo e retiro apenas uma `string`, exatamente um `PK` desse arquivo?

```
$conteudo = serialize($array);      
$caminho ='';
file_put_contents($caminho, $conteudo);
```

Conteúdo do *array* salvo:

`a:1:{s:5:"items";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{s:2:"pk";i:1338838365890273563;}}}`

Comment: Não sei se ficou claro, mais eu quero obter somente o código depois do i: Que seria 1338838365890273563.

Vlw!!!!

Comment: você recebe exatamente isso `a:1:{s:5:"items";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{s:2:"pk";i:1338838365890273563;}}}` ?

Comment: voce pode usar o [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php) para ler o arquivo e [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.unserialize.php) para o texto voltar a ser array

Comment: Faz exatamente o inverso so que usando file get contents e depois unserialize, terá um array com os mesmos dados de antes... (Desculpe, estou no celular e não consigo postar como uma resposta descente)

Answer (score 0):

Se for só para extrair o número da string, você pode fazer apenas isso:

```
$value =  'a:1:{s:5:"items";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{s:2:"pk";i:1338838365890273563;}}}';

preg_match('/"pk"\;i\:([0-9]+)\;/', $value, $d);

echo $d[1];
```

Agora se você deseja rever o valor do array, pode reverter o serialize desta forma:

```
$conteudo_salvo = 'a:1:{s:5:"items";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{s:2:"pk";i:1338838365890273563;}}}';
echo unserialize($conteudo_salvo)['items'][0]['pk'];
```

Porém, há um problema que pode modificar o comportamento da conversão, é que o número serializado é convertido para notação científica, ou seja, perdeu-se a referência completa do número inteiro:

```
 $a = array(
         'items' => array( 
                     0 => array( 'pk' => 1338838365890273563
                          ) 
                   )
    );
```

Na saída do `unserialize`, ele ficará como notação científica, pois o valor é muito grande para ser serializado: **1.3388383658903E+18**
 Como fazer para que o serialize seja feito corretamente, passe-o em formato de string:

```
$a = array(
         'items' => array( 
                     0 => array( 'pk' => "1338838365890273563"
                          ) 
                   )
    );
```

Fazendo isso, basta utilizar as funções desta forma:

```
$s = serialize($a);
$u = unserialize($s);

print_r($a);
print_r($u);
```

**OBS:** Três formas simples de transformar o valor inteiro para string:

```
$a["items"][0]["pk"] = '"' . $a["items"][0]["pk"] . '"';
```

ou

```
$a["items"][0]["pk"] = (string) $a["items"][0]["pk"];
```

ou

```
$a["items"][0]["pk"] = strval($a["items"][0]["pk"]);
```

Comment: Obrigado cara, ajudou muito. Vlw, abraço!

Comment: Boa tarde, em vez de 'serialize' optei por usar json_encode($array) para ter um formato mais fácil de acesso, pois os dados vão ser armazenados no banco de dados. Os dados do array com o json_encode ficou: {"items":[{"pk":1338838365890273563}]}. Para pegar a "PK" eu utilizo essa mesma lógica?